# Como pegar elemento por id Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html5

Tenho o seguinte código HTML gerado por PHP:

```
<li id="15" data-status="Em Processo" class="list-group-item tasks-list-group">
    <p style="display: none">#15</p>                                                                            
    <span class="badge" style="background-color:#67A6DF">Processo</span>                                    
    08/12/2016<br>
    Teste 2                                     
    <p style="display: none">Média</p>
    <p class="fantasy">Teste</p>
    <div class="type-average"></div>
    <i class="fa fa-flask fa-lg test-task" aria-hidden="true"></i>                                  
    <i class="fa fa-times fa-lg cancel-task" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</li>
```

Quando clico no `<i class="fa fa-flask fa-lg test-task" aria-hidden="true"></i>` ele deve trocar o status da tarefa para **Teste**.

Mas preciso pegar o ID da tag `li`, mas não posso pegar por `.parent()`, porque a sequência dos elementos do HTML mudam.

Mas tentei o seguinte:

```
$(".test-task").on('click', function(){
    var element = $(this).find('.tasks-list-group').attr('id');    
    var idTask = $(element).val();   
    alert(idTask);  
});
```

Mas retorna indefinido.

Alguém tem algum ideia do que eu posso fazer?

Comment: Esta retornando indefinido pois a sua variavel 'element' traz uma string com o nome do ID. Porém o seletor jquery precisa de "#" + id. Ou seja $("#" + element).val();

Comment: Você também pode usar o closest. Dentro da função do click em .test-task. var idTask = $(this).closest("li").attr("id").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode pegar por .parents() independente da ordem e da quantidade de elementos. Desde que o pai sempre seja um li:

```
var $parent = $(this).parents('li');
```

https://api.jquery.com/parents/